# Ruby Winapi Socket TCP/IP

Tags: ruby, socket, winapi

Olá,
Atualmente eu preciso criar uma conexão em ruby usando apenas winapi.
Tudo funciona perfeitamente, porém, quando o cliente envia uma informação, ele precisa de EXATAMENTE UMA RESPOSTA, caso não haja resposta ou haja mais de um dado enviado pelo servidor, ele simplesmente fica instável(o ping sobe), eu preciso que isso não aconteça.

Aqui segue o receive, send, e o select, que uso para verificar se há uma informação para o cliente ler.

```
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Checks waiting data's status.
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def select
    result = Select.call 0, [1, @descriptor].pack('ll'), 0, 0, [0, 0].pack('ll')
    SocketError.check if result == -1
    return result
  end
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Checks if data is waiting.
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def ready?
    return self.select != 0
  end  
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Returns receieved data.
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def recv(length, flags = 0)
    buffer = "\0" * length
    result = Recv.call @descriptor, buffer, length, flags
    SocketError.check if result == -1
    return '' if result == 0
    return buffer[0, result].unpack("c*").pack("c*") # gets rid of a bunch of \0
  end
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # Sends data to a host.
  #----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def send(data, flags = 0)
    result = Send.call @descriptor, data, data.size, flags
    SocketError.check if result == -1
    p result
    return result
  end
```

Vale lembrar, que isso acontece apena em WAN, em LAN o ping é estável(não, não é a conexão).
Alguém tem alguma dica ou solução?